# Firestore security rules recommended use and performance

Tags: firebase, performance, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I wrote the following Firestore security rules to check the user document reads and writes. When I run this code through the simulator in the Firebase console for a create document, the Chrome tab freezes for >90 seconds until I dismiss the simulation result. This made me wonder if the security rules are not meant to be used the way I implemented them. Can you please advise on my implementation and if it is within practical and intended use? If the code is acceptable then how can I run this in the simulator without freezing the tab?

```
rules_version = '2';
match /users/{userId} {
  allow get: if isSignedIn();
  allow list: if isSignedIn() && request.query.limit <= 50;
  allow create: if request.auth.uid == userId
    && request.get('resource', null) != null
    && !isUserDeleted(request.resource.data) 
    && !isUserBanned(request.resource.data)
    && isAffectedKeysValid(request.resource.data.keys())
    && isIncomingDataValid();
  allow update: if request.auth.uid == userId
    && request.get('resource', null) != null
    && !isUserDeleted(request.resource.data) 
    && !isUserBanned(request.resource.data)
    && isAffectedKeysValid(getAffectedKeys())
    && isIncomingDataValid();

  function isUserDeleted(userData) {
    return userData.get('deleted', false) == true;
  }

  function isUserBanned(userData) {
    return userData.get('permanently_banned', false) == true 
      || (userData.get('ban_expire_time', '') is timestamp 
            && userData.ban_expire_time >= request.time);
  }
  
  function isAffectedKeysValid(affectedKeys) {
    return affectedKeys.hasOnly([
      'id',
      'first_name',
      'birthday',
      'about',
      'images',
      'country',
      'geohash_5',
      'geohash_6',
      'last_seen',
      'app_locale',
      'deleted'
      ]);
  }

  function isIncomingDataValid() {
    let incomingData = request.resource.data;
    return incomingData.get('id', '') is string 
      && incomingData.get('id', userId) == userId 
      && incomingData.get('first_name', '') is string
      && incomingData.first_name.size() <= 100
      && incomingData.get('birthday', request.time) is timestamp
      && incomingData.get('birthday', request.time) <= request.time
      && incomingData.get('birthday', request.time) >= timestamp.date(1900,1,1)
      && incomingData.get('about', '') is string
      && incomingData.get('about', '').size() <= 700
      && incomingData.get('images', []) is list
      && incomingData.get('images', '').size() <= 6
      && incomingData.get('country', '') is string
      && incomingData.get('country', '').size() <= 2
      && incomingData.get('geohash_5', '') is string
      && incomingData.get('geohash_5', '').size() <= 5
      && incomingData.get('geohash_6', '') is string
      && incomingData.get('geohash_6', '').size() <= 6
      && incomingData.get('last_seen', request.time) is timestamp
      && incomingData.get('last_seen', request.time) <= request.time
      && incomingData.get('app_locale', '') is string
      && incomingData.get('app_locale', '').size() <= 2
      && incomingData.get('deleted', false) is bool;
  }

  function getAffectedKeys() {
    return request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys();
  }
}
```

*Note: I wrote 350 lines of security Firestore rules to secure several kinds of documents in the database and they all generally follow the same format so I only posted the portion that checks the user document reads and writes. The freeze is shorter with the code above alone but it still freezes a considerable duration nonetheless.*

Comment: Can you update what's in incomingData()?

Comment: It's request.resource.data @flutroid

Comment: Your rules look ok. Fyi I have more complex rules and the simulator will work just fine, have you tried on another computer? Note that when your rules grow larger it is advised to use the emulator to test them, makes things much easier

Comment: @l1b3rty I do run them in an emulator too but the simulator helps me spot bugs or see what happened step by step. I found a semi solution of opening the simulator in Firefox instead of chromium based browsers, for some reason it runs much better in Firefox.